# IntelliJ auto build and I can't debug my application anymore after I change my code

Tags: debugging, intellij-13

I have some bad experience when debug in intellij, after I change my code, I can't use postman to call request anymore, I must debug my application again. I just want maybe command my code and intellij debug auto shutdown or rerun. How to turn off that behavior, thank you

I just want maybe command my code and intellij debug auto shutdown or rerun. How to turn off that behavior

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide something like a capture of that